# On resonance of an RLC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, oscillators, resonance

How do I prove that the width of resonance in an RLC circuit is the inverse of the proper time of the circuit?

I know that the amplitude of charge in the condensator is
$$Q(\omega)=\frac{V_\text{max}/L}{\sqrt{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\gamma\omega)^2}}$$
So I tried to show from the equality 
$Q(\omega_0\pm\Delta\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Q(\omega_0)$
that $\Delta\omega = 2 / \gamma$ but the expression is to hard. Do I need to do approximations?

Comment: What have you done to try to figure out the answer yourself?

Comment: Yes, you need the approximation $\Delta \omega \ll \omega_0$. Also, you should ignore everything in the expression except for what's inside the square root, since that's the important part.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper time"?

Comment: Please define $\gamma$. Is this a series circuit or parallel circuit? Is it voltage or current driven?

Comment: Something is wrong with your denominator. First term under the radical has units of $\omega^4$ and the second term has $\omega^2$.  Unless $\gamma$ has units of inverse time, too.

Comment: $\gamma=R/L$ and THE time constant is $\tau=2/\gamma$.